# I want to delete my ubuntu partition from windows 11 but i dont know which is the right one to delete ,pls help me with the below ss

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, 20.04, ros

[The image contains the disk partition shown in disk configuration on win11 as well as space occupied by ubuntu which is obtained by typing df -h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGCow.jpg)

Comment: 22.25 gb, 552 mb but you must install easybcd and add windows bootloader to 1st partition.

Comment: If UEFI which it should be, you need to make sure Windows is the default boot loader. Normally you can change that in UEFI settings (not UEFI boot menu). Or in Ubuntu with efibootmgr, except HP systems. https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on & https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on

Comment: I'd always boot the OS you want to delete & note what it is using & what maybe impacted rather than guess from what another OS sees of it. Also ensure the *soon to be deleted OS* is not involved in the booting, or you risk being locked out of all OSes on the box (*particularly the case if the unwanted OS was installed later*), if it is you use the tools of the wanted OS to take over boot ownership.

Comment: @TalaatEtman , what if I directly delete the 55gb partition without adding bootloader,can you pls tell the necessity of adding windows  bootloader to it?

Comment: @vigneshs Since GRUB does the booting, you will enter grub rescue if you don't add windows bootloader.